# JQuery selector bug - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird JQuery bug that I cannot find the cause for.

There is an edit button for each row that changes the title and body cells to an input and textarea field.

It works for the first row but not for any other rows

If I click the first row, it will work for consecutive rows.

Can someone please have a look over my code

```
@extends('layouts')

@section('content')
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Diary Application</h1>
  <button style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary"><a href={{ url('newEntry') }}>New Entry<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></button>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($entries as $entry)
      <tr id={{ $entry->id }}>
        <td>{{ $entry->created_at->format('l h:ia d/m/Y') }}</td>
        <td id="title">{{ $entry->title }}</td>
        <td id="body">{{ $entry->body }}</td>
        <td id="buttons"><button class="btn btn-danger"><a href={{ url("/deleteEntry/$entry->id")}}>Delete</a></button> &nbsp; <button class="btn btn-warning" id="edit" data-id={{ $entry->id }}>Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  @endsection

 @section('scripts')
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button#edit").click( function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var titleField = $("tr#" + id + " > td#title");
        var contentField = $("tr#" + id + " > td#body");
        alert("tr#" + id + " > td#body");
        alert($("tr#" + id + " > td#body").html());
        titleField.replaceWith("<td style='vertical-align: center;'><input type=text name='title' value=" + titleField.html() + "></td>");
        contentField.replaceWith("<td style='vertical-align: center;'><textarea rows='3' name='body'> " + contentField.html() + "</textarea></td>");
        $("tr#" + id + " > td#buttons").append("&nbsp; <button class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>");
        $("tr#" + id + " > td#buttons > .btn-warning").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
    });
  </script>
  @endsection
```

Comment: use `class` name instead of `id`, because `id` should be unique.

Comment: `"button#edit"` is the first warning sign: ID should be unique. Use classes. Also, you're overcomplicating things with `$("tr#" + id + " > td#title")`, because `$(this).closest("tr").find(".title")` (after you change `title` to be a class) saves you having to mess around with the `data-id`.

Comment: In Jquery whenever you want to bind an event to more than one element then you have to use common class name for those elements on which you want to bind the same event. And here in your code i can see that you have binded the event using id as selector which will bind the event on the very first element which will be available from top in dom, thats the reason you are not able to perform event on any other row.

Comment: Thanks guys! Saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `id` to `class` and try the below code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.edit").click( function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var titleField = tr.find(".title");
        var contentField = tr.find(".body");
        alert(contentField);
        alert(contentField.html());
        titleField.replaceWith("<td style='vertical-align: center;'><input type=text name='title' value=" + titleField.html() + "></td>");
        contentField.replaceWith("<td style='vertical-align: center;'><textarea rows='3' name='body'> " + contentField.html() + "</textarea></td>");
        tr.find(".buttons").append("&nbsp; <button class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>")
           .find(".btn-warning") // use chaining
           .prop('disabled', true);// use prop instead of attr
    });
});
```

Your HTML should be,

```
<tr id={{ $entry->id }}>
    <td>{{ $entry->created_at->format('l h:ia d/m/Y') }}</td>
    <td class="title">{{ $entry->title }}</td>
    <td class="body">{{ $entry->body }}</td>
    <td class="buttons"><button class="btn btn-danger"><a href={{ url("/deleteEntry/$entry->id")}}>Delete</a></button> &nbsp; <button class="btn btn-warning edit" data-id={{ $entry->id }}>Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Snippet,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.edit").click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var titleField = tr.find(".title");
    var contentField = tr.find(".body");
    titleField.replaceWith("<td style='vertical-align: center;'><input type=text name='title' value=" + titleField.html() + "></td>");
    contentField.replaceWith("<td style='vertical-align: center;'><textarea rows='3' name='body'> " + contentField.html() + "</textarea></td>");
    tr.find(".buttons").append("&nbsp; <button class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>")
      .find(".btn-warning") // use chaining
      .prop('disabled', true); // use prop instead of attr
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>Date 1</td>
    <td class="title">Title1</td>
    <td class="body">Body1</td>
    <td class="buttons"><button class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#">Delete</a></button> &nbsp; <button class="btn btn-warning edit" data-id="1">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>Date 2</td>
    <td class="title">Title2</td>
    <td class="body">Body2</td>
    <td class="buttons"><button class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#">Delete</a></button> &nbsp; <button class="btn btn-warning edit" data-id="2">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>Date 3</td>
    <td class="title">Title3</td>
    <td class="body">Body3</td>
    <td class="buttons"><button class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#">Delete</a></button> &nbsp; <button class="btn btn-warning edit" data-id="3">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: THanks everyone - you guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

First change the IDs to Classes &

Use jQuery's `$.closest()` like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button#edit").click( function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr"); // This will give you the TR in which your elements reside.
        ....
        your rest of the code with some modifications
        ....              
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating several **button** tags with de same id (#edit), in the html document an id attibute must be unique, you could use a class selector like this.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning edit" data-id={{ $entry->id }}>Edit</button>
```

And then in your javascript use:

```
$("button.btn.edit").click( function() {...});
```